# find %userprofile% folder on another computer

Tags: active-directory, profile

Is there a deterministic way for a domain-user to find the `%userprofile%` path for their equivalent profile on a remote Windows computer?

The root of the filesystem on the remote computer is shared.

My best strategy so far is to guess at the naming convention of profile folders. I expect it will be something like `\\sharename\C$\Users\<username>` or `\\sharename\C$\Users\<username>.<domain>` or `\\sharename\C$\Users\<username>001` or something like that, but I'd prefer something more reliable than guess and test-for-existence.

My ultimate goal is to write a logon script that requires no user interaction which retrieves files from a known location within the user's profile on the remote computer. It's like building a limited version of a roaming profile. I'm open to using whatever tools allow me to build such a script (.NET app, VBScript, tbd).

Answer (score 0):

If you want on all the computers+servers

```
    Import-module activedirectory    

Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | `
Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\users\"}}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to use this. This appears to test for the existence of folders with a known path. I'm looking for an _unknown_ path which points to the userprofile folder for a specific user on a specific machine (both the user and machine are variable parameters).